# Javascript redirect

Tags: javascript, servlets, mapping

I am working with javascript and here is what I am trying to do:
1. Send a get request which looks like "http://localhost:8080/myapp/verify.htm?verifyId=Agkvhs"

My requests reaches my verify.jsp in which I have javascript which does some special things and then should redirect to another url WITH the verifyId .
My code looks like this:

```
function saveAndRedirect() {
    var verifyId = "<%=request.getParameter("verifyId")%>";
    var redirectUrl = "registrationVerify?verifyId=" + verifyId;
    window.alert("Got value " + redirectUrl);
    window.location = redirectUrl;

}
```

However this does not work. I have an alert which shows me the correct URL with the appended parameter as I expect.
In my web.xml file I have a servlet mapping with the following:

```
 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>RegistrationVerificationServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/registrationVerify*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

This mapping was workign before I appended the verifyId to the URL, I could see my request beign redicted to the servlet, since I appended this param it is not working. Any ideas much appreciated!

If this is not the ideal way to do this, please let me know any alternative.

Thanks

Comment: *However this does not work*, can you please elaborate this? What happens instead? Blank page? Error page? Do the servlet get invoked? Is the parameter missing in request map? What do you see in browser address bar now? Etcetera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your url-pattern is suspicious.

Use either

```
/registrationVerify
```

to cover the exact path or

```
/registrationVerify/*
```

to cover the part of pathinfo. Note that you don't explicitly need the last one to be able to accept request parameters, if you'd thought that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a long-shot, but does this line change help?

```
window.location=window.location.href+redirectURL;
```